How can I determine, for an arbitrary polyglossia language, whether it is RTL or LTR?
I'm looking for a macro that will tell me, for any given polyglossia language (or any loaded language), whether that language is LTR or RTL.
For example, in gloss-urdu.ldf I see the command:
\PolyglossiaSetup{urdu}{
  bcp47=ur,
  bcp47-language=ur,
  bcp47-script=Arab,
  script=Arabic,
  direction=RL,
  scripttag=arab,
  langtag=URD,
  hyphennames={urdu,nohyphenation},
  fontsetup=true,
  localnumeral=urdunumerals
  %TODO localalph={abjad,abjad}
}

I'm looking for a macro that will give me RL.

\prop_item:Nn \l_xpg_langsetup_prop { <lang> / direction }

When I put that into the main body I get Undefined control sequence.

Did you put that with a suitable category code regime? \ExplSyntaxOn \prop_item:Nn \l_xpg_langsetup_prop { <lang> / direction } \ExplSyntaxOff...

Most of the information about a language is stored in a property list called \l_xpg_langsetup_prop. The entries are of the format <lang> / <tag>.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \langdir { m }
  {
    \prop_item:Nn \l_xpg_langsetup_prop { #1 / direction }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\langdir{urdu}

\end{document}


That's curious: I get an error: `! Undefined control sequence.
 \l_xpg_langsetup_prop
l.14 \langdir{urdu}`

@adam.baker Make sure you have the latest version of polyglossia.

Thanks, that did it! (just three months old...)

@adam.baker well three months ago the property list was named \g_xpg_langsetup_prop :)
